# What is maximum size of texture (Andengine)

Tags: android, andengine

What is maximum size of texture that should be used in andengine. I used

```
this.diamondTexture = new Texture(2048, 512, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
```

When loading in device(HTC G1 T-Mobile) it shows blank screen. After reducing the image size and  when replacing the above line with this

```
this.diamondTexture = new Texture(1024, 512, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
```

Its running . Whats the problem ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Common approach - texture max size is 1024x1024. Some hi-end devices can handle 2048x2048 textures, but it`s better to use 1024x1024 size if you want your application to run on almost all devices.

Answer (score 1):

Your device might be running out of memory when using the larger texture. Check your logCat for errors.

Comment: No error in logcat. Any max size of Texture ? But some time in emulator  its shows Force to close / Wait