# Sprite.setImage() in andengine

Tags: android, sprite, andengine

I'm developing a game for Android using andEngine. I have to change sprite images dynamically. In J2ME, i used

```
sprite.setImage("img.png");
```

But in andengine, i not able to find method

```
//sprite.setImage(?); -In andengine
```

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think use TextureRegion is a better way to change sprite's image.

Add the following code in org.anddev.andengine.entity.sprite

```
public void setTextureRegion(TextureRegion textureRegion) {
    this.mTextureRegion = textureRegion;
}
```

Then you can change image by this method. You can check the andengine samples to see how to create a texture region from an image.

PS, if `mTextureRegion` is final, just remove the `final` syntax.

Comment: This way is the easiest way of changing sprite's image..Thanks..!

Comment: This has not been possible for a long time. As of at least 2 years ago the field mTextureRegion has been marked final, here's the source  https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/entity/sprite/Sprite.java?source=c

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `TiledSprite` instead of simple `Sprite`. That `TiledSprite` takes `TiledTextureRegion` as parameter. You create a single `TiledTextureRegion` containing an image with all the small images you need to set on your sprite. Then you call `setCurrentTileIndex(index)` where `index` is the index of the image you need to place on your sprite.

Comment: What about the width and height constraints of that image?

Comment: And i need to check pixel level collision so i'm using PixelPerfectAnimatedSprite,so can i check pixel level collision for TiledSprite as well?

Comment: @Andy Sorry I haven't used pixel perfect collision so I don't know. I write my own collision functions depending on the sprites. And in regard to the width and height, are you referring to the big image containing the small ones or the small image?

Comment: big image containing small images whose size is exceeding 1024x1024,so it might be a constraint..

Comment: Indeed if the size is exceeding `1024x1024` low end devices will have to suffer, I had that problem myself when I was developing my game.

Comment: So how did you overcome this?

Comment: In your case with TiledTextureRegion I'm not sure how you can do this, in my case I made multiple sprites with separate Atlases and TextureRegions allocated, to build what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to do it manually, that is detach/hide the sprite and attach/show a different one.

Comment: I have to change 5 to 6 images for a single sprite dynamically,so i have to use 6 different sprites.. Any method in which dis can be done using a single sprite?

Comment: Yes, or maybe you can use animated sprite instead. Don't worry about the number of Sprites, AndEngine should handle it easily.

Comment: I'm using an animated sprite for which i have to replace another 5 to 6 images which again has few frames.. Is there a simple way by which i can do dis without creating a different sprite?

Comment: See the great answer by Alexandru Averescu.

Comment: If i use TiledSprite,image width and height is exceeding 1024x1024,from which am forced to use different images.Any equivalent method for setImage() in J2ME for changing sprite images?

Comment: Sprites larger than 1024x1024 may not be a problem, I tried 4096x4096 some time ago and it worked on the devices I could test it on.

Comment: Not sure, I would expect it not to work on older versions and work on newer. Is there any reason why it should not be so?

Comment: I know, but is there a reason why it should be problem on _newer_ devices? Old versions of Android are now pretty rare.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815141/what-is-maximum-size-of-texture-andengine..

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by detaching my sprite, assigning a new Sprite (mySprite = new Sprite(...)) to my sprite and attaching my sprite again.