# setTextureRegion AnimatedSprite

Tags: android, andengine, animated

I'm developping a game which implements gif sprites...
After start with gif I used png image and for change the TextureRegion of my sprite I followed this guide: [Sprite.setImage() in andengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667668/sprite-setimage-in-andengine) and it worked very well.

Now I want to do the same thing with AnimatedSprite. Can someone tell me How i can edit the org.anddev.andengine.entity.sprite.AnimatedSprite.java to create:

`sprite.setAnimatedTextureRegion(PixelPerfectTiledTextureRegion textureRegion)`

P.S I use also [PixelPerfect](https://github.com/MakersF/AndEngineCollisionsExtension)

Answer (score 1):

The `AnimatedSprite` class uses the same texture region declared in `BaseSprite`, so the code in the link you gave will work - just paste it in the AnimatedSprite.java file:

```
public void setTiledTextureRegion(TiledTextureRegion textureRegion) {
    this.mTextureRegion = textureRegion;
}
```

*Note:* If the different tiled textures have different number of tiles (So each has a different animation parameters associated with it) you should handle it in your code. It may get complicated, so I'd just create a new `AnimatedSprite` instead of replacing the texture region.